# Create delegate of getter with changed return type

Tags: c#, .net

I need to map all of properties to Func. How would I do that?

I've got class

```
class A 
{
    public int SomeIntValue { get; }
    public string SomeStringValue { get; }
    public Dictionary<...> SomeDictionary { get; }
}
```

and dictionary `Dictionary<string, Func<A, object>>`.
I'm trying to create delegate for the getter methods but I can't really figure out how to do it.

In such a way, it doesn't work and it make sense why. I need to do it indirectly but how?

```
(Func<TType, object>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TType, object>), null, property.GetGetMethod())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you've got is that converting from a `Func<A, int>` to `Func<A, object>` is not a representation preserving conversion, so it is not allowed via the variance modifiers provided on the declaration of the Func family of delegates. For value types, you need an extra IL instruction to be added which is a boxing conversion. Below I give a solution that generates a dynamic method to add the required instruction when necessary (i.e. when the return value is a value type). It is also more efficient because it directly invokes the property rather than relying on reflection to handle the invocation.

```
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public static Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> GetGetMethods<T>()
{
    var getMethods = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>>();
    foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {    
        Func<T, object> del;
        if (prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
        {
            var dynMethod = new DynamicMethod(string.Format("Dynamic_Get_{0}_{1}", typeof(T).Name, prop.Name), typeof(object), new[] { typeof(T) }, typeof(T).Module);
            var ilGen = dynMethod.GetILGenerator();
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetGetMethod());
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Box, prop.PropertyType);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            del = (Func<T, object>)dynMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, object>));
        }
        else
        {
            del = (Func<T, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, object>), null, prop.GetGetMethod());
        }

        getMethods[prop.Name] = del;
    }

    return getMethods;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know generating IL is a thing! I feel like this is a little overkill when what the OP wants seems simple. Anyway, I like solutions like this! +1

Comment: It look super. I was thinking about manipulating Expression<...> but your solution looks really great

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can create the delegate by using the method group `somePropertyInfo.GetValue`:

```
Func<A, object> del = somePropertyInfo.GetValue;
```

And then you can put that into the dictionary.

You don't need the `GetGetMethod` call because `GetValue` will call the getter. That method is for getting the property as a `MethodInfo` object. Here, you don't need a `MethodInfo`.

Comment: It looks to be working but I had to change it to `Func<object, object> del = ...`

Comment: One gotcha with this is that this is still using reflection so if the getter throws an exception it will be wrapped in a TargetInvocationException. Also since it still binds the method through reflection it is much slower than a normal delegate invocation. See my answer for an implementation that directly invokes the delegate.